# git, do not commit so easily after merge

Tags: git, merge

My git workflow is to edit some files, add the changes as needed (often with `add -p`) and then `git commit -v` to review the changes in VIM and then write the message and commit it if i am happy, or exit the editor without saving the message if I think it still needs work.

But with merges, it usually goes: 1. git merge, 2. resolve conflicts, 3. `git add` the files after clearing conflicts...

And then at this point, I try my usual `git commit -v` to inspect the changes, and if i think i still need some work, just exiting the editor without saving the commit message will still commit it with the default "Merge commit 123455".

How can i stop that for good? I do not want defaults that makes me make mistakes. It drives me crazy :/

Comment: I suppose the real question then is, why are you attempting to merge work that isn't ready to be merged?

Comment: I prefer to review the potential-commit with `git diff --cached` rather than `git commit -v`, but to avoid committing a merge with the default message, you could just switch to a habit of "delete entire commit text to abort commit".

Comment: I would agree with @Makoto to review your code first before merging. GIT MERGE will always result into a commit describing the merging action. If you want you can create patch from one branch and apply it on top of the other. Review your code and then COMMIT!

Comment: @Makoto my use case is: coworker sends in pull request with 3 features. I merge it to HEAD, `git reset`, `git add -p` select only the first feature and branch out for a new pull request. repeat 2 more times. Now i have one PR for each feature.

Comment: @manishrw yeah, actually, sometimes i don't even use merge. i do `git diff master...12345 | patch -p1`... but sometimes i just use `git merge 12345`, isn't there anything that is as convenient as git merge that do not result in a commit? i think my actual problem is i forgot the git reset sometimes. but using patch all the time is also inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start at an earlier point when keeping this workflow. Check

```
git merge --no-commit
```

As out of documentation:

> With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and do
>   not autocommit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak
>   the merge result before committing.

However, you should check the changes before trying to merge it at all. So just do a git diff  before the merge action and you will not end up in that situation.

Comment: all the answers here are good and good advice, but that is the one that i believe "solve" it. i can easily add an alias for merge to be merge without commit and have a consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested I would also review the changes first with `git diff --cached`, but if you would like to cancel the current commit, while using `git commit -v` you can always exit `vim` with an non-zero error code, this should abort the commit, like: `:cq`

Comment: nobody uses `:cq` to exit vim when they do not want to commit :( everyone's finger-memory, well mine at least, goes directly to `:q!` for "i am not ready for this commit" because that is what works every time you are not merging (which is 90% of the time you commit something)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving the default commit message for the merge commit alone, you should be able to delete it completely, which will cancel the commit process.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to avoid. i do it most of the time, but sometimes i forget because it is not "normal" to have a commit message already there when i type `git commit -v`. inconsistencies in interface are the mother of all human-error!